# Use =.. to define the predicate subterm(T1,T2)

Tags: prolog

I want to review my lessons quickly by doing some practice. But I have no solution for those practice to check. Could you give me a solution, so when I get stucke. I could find some guidance here quickly.The first question is described below. Thanks in advance.

Question1. We recall that the built in predicate  T  =.. L is satisfied if T is a term and L is the list that contains the functor and the main subterms of L.
For example, f(a,g(b)) =.. L is satisfied when L = [ f, a, g(b) ],and a =.. List is satisfied when List = [a].

Use =.. to define the predicate subterm(T1,T2) which is satisfied when T1 is a subterm of T2. You may assume that T1 and T2 have no variables. You may also want to use the built in predicates atomic(X) or compound(X) that check if X is an atomic term and a structure, in this order.

My solution is:

```
subterm(X,[X]):-atom(X),!.
subterm(T1,T2):-
compound(T1),
T1=..U,
U=[X|Y],
T2=Y.
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't need atomic/1 or compound/1, rather member/2. Please show what you tried.

Comment: We'd be glad to help once you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am busy with preparing one exam. I wonder if I have enough time to solve all the practice our professor gave. As long as I have an idea, I will post it here to get your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a term T is a subterm of itself, the definition can be very simple:

```
subterm(T, T).
subterm(T1, T2) :-
  T2 =.. [_|As],
  member(A, As),
  subterm(T1, A).
```

Anyway, you can see as the predicate above implements a 'lazy' visit of the tree structured term.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I feel ashamed to post simple question directly without thinking. And the question looks like not so clear.